# Window 'Figure' keeps closing after running for a while

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, fuzzy-logic

I was just trying a simple fuzzy project on my own. And when I'm running it, the Plot window/Figure window keeps closing automatically. Terminal also shows no sign of error, it's just the window closing on its own after its done running the code. Here's my code.
I'm using Visual Studio Code by the way.

```
import numpy as np
import skfuzzy as fuzz
from skfuzzy import control as ctrl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class fuzzyNilai:

    def __init__(self):
        self.forum = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 11, 1), 'forum')
        self.disiplin = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 11, 1), 'disiplin')
        self.NilaiQuizUjian = ctrl.Antecedent(np.arange(0, 11, 1), 'nilai')
        self.NilaiAkhir = ctrl.Consequent(np.arange(0, 101, 1), 'nilaiakhir')

    def membership(self):
        self.forum.automf(3)
        self.disiplin.automf(3)
        self.NilaiQuizUjian.automf(3)

plt = fuzzyNilai()
plt.membership()
plt.forum.view()
```

Is there any way to keep the plot/figure window keeps running without automatically closed? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line at the end of the code:

```
input()
```

[image]